# SessionAware does not inject session Object

Tags: spring, session, dependency-injection, struts2, struts

Once more here I come with a question of s2, I'm a beginner at it and got some trouble finding examples.

I'm building a menu service which depends upon a login, which is give when the user enters at start page. Once the login has been made, I store the user object into the session by doing the follow:

```
@Override
public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {
....
         
// verifica se o parametro do CPF veio no get e tenta logar o usuario
if (!StringUtils.isBlank(request.getParameter(USER_CPF_REQUEST))) {

if ( doLogin(request, session) ) {
   return Action.SUCCESS;
}
```

and then the doLogin method

```
Usuario usuario = getServico().buscar( Long.valueOf(cpf) );
//Caso o usuário exista, guarda na session
if (usuario != null){
    session.setAttribute(USER_HANDLE, usuario);
    return true;
}
```

Now comes the problem, I have a MenuBean injected on the MenuAction by the following xml piece on ApplicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="menuService" class="br.com.autenticis.renacon.ejb.MenuBean" />

    <bean id="menuAction" scope="prototype" class="br.com.autenticis.renacon.actions.MenuAction">
        <constructor-arg ref="menuService" />
    </bean>
```

And the menuAction is declared as follow:

```
public class MenuAction extends ActionSupport implements Preparable, SessionAware
```

By doing so I need to implement the session set with a private member

```
private Map<String, Object> session;
....
@Override
public void setSession(Map<String, Object> session) {
   this.session = session;
}
```

The failing part of all its the method bellow, the session object is null at debugging:

```
    public String execute() {
            if ( session.containsKey( LoginInterceptor.USER_HANDLE) ){
                Usuario u = (Usuario) session.get( LoginInterceptor.USER_HANDLE);
                setMenu( servico.getMenuPerfil( u.getPerfil() ) );
                return Action.SUCCESS;
            }
            
            return input();
        }
```

Does anyone know why? or how to implement it? Looking at the code above, I need 'Perfil' from the user which is logged on, if the session contains the key to the user object I get it and then use the perfil to populate the Menu through the setter and return SUCESS, otherwise it'll return INPUT which will lead to the login screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some ours I managed to discover the error. wich lies not in the program but in the struts.xml, I've written a custom stack for the application:

```
<!-- stack seguro --> 
<!-- 
<interceptor-stack name="defaultLoginStack"> 
<interceptor-ref name="logger" /> 
<interceptor-ref name="params" /> 
<interceptor-ref name="login" /> 
<interceptor-ref name="prepare" /> 
<interceptor-ref name="chain" /> 
<interceptor-ref name="modelDriven" /> 
<interceptor-ref name="modelDriven" /> 
<interceptor-ref name="fileUpload" /> 
<interceptor-ref name="staticParams" /> 
<interceptor-ref name="params" /> 
<interceptor-ref name="conversionError" /> 
<interceptor-ref name="validation" /> 
<interceptor-ref name="workflow" /> 
</interceptor-stack> 
-->
```

And somewhat forgot to include session-related items, with the defaultLoginStack changed to

```
<interceptor-stack name="defaultLoginStack"> 
<interceptor-ref name="login" /> 
<interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" /> 
</interceptor-stack>
```

I'm now able to use session injected correctly.

Comment: Remeber to be cautious when messing with stack :)